# Updating from Fedora 37 to 39 - everything works but the filesystem

Tags: fedora, upgrade, dnf

I had a machine still working on Fedora 37 and used the instructions in [Fedora Docs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/upgrading-fedora-offline/#sect-can-i-use-dnf-system-upgrade-to-upgrade-to-a-pre-release) to upgrade to 39. All went very well and the system seems to behave fine. The only exception is the package filesystem, which gives me a transaction error every time I try. The output is:

```
 pc@pcdesk-fedora: ~ via  4GiB/31GiB | 0B/82GiB with /bin/bash [Thu Nov 30 2023 10:33PM (EST-0500)][9:min up]
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────
└─> sudo dnf update --allowerasing -y --refresh --verbose
[sudo] password for pc: 
Loaded plugins: builddep, changelog, config-manager, copr, debug, debuginfo-install, download, generate_completion_cache, groups-manager, needs-restarting, notify-packagekit, playground, repoclosure, repodiff, repograph, repomanage, reposync, system-upgrade
DNF version: 4.18.1
cachedir: /var/cache/dnf
User-Agent: constructed: 'libdnf (Fedora Linux 39; workstation; Linux.x86_64)'
Copr repo for PyCharm owned by phracek                                                                                                                                                     28 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00    
reviving: 'copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:phracek:PyCharm' can be revived - repomd matches.
copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:phracek:PyCharm: using metadata from Thu 10 Aug 2023 11:35:19 AM EDT.
countme: no event for fedora: window already counted
Fedora 39 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                                        282 kB/s |  25 kB     00:00    
reviving: 'fedora' can be revived - metalink checksums match.
fedora: using metadata from Tue 31 Oct 2023 08:12:39 PM EDT.
Fedora 39 openh264 (From Cisco) - x86_64                                                                                                                                                   15 kB/s | 989  B     00:00    
reviving: 'fedora-cisco-openh264' can be revived - metalink checksums match.
fedora-cisco-openh264: using metadata from Tue 14 Mar 2023 06:57:01 AM EDT.
countme: no event for updates: window already counted
Fedora 39 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                                                                                                               68 kB/s |  23 kB     00:00    
reviving: 'updates' can be revived - metalink checksums match.
updates: using metadata from Thu 30 Nov 2023 08:15:12 PM EST.
google-chrome                                                                                                                                                                             8.8 kB/s | 1.3 kB     00:00    
reviving: 'google-chrome' can be revived - repomd matches.
google-chrome: using metadata from Wed 29 Nov 2023 04:31:19 PM EST.
RPM Fusion for Fedora 39 - Free                                                                                                                                                           8.4 kB/s | 3.6 kB     00:00    
reviving: 'rpmfusion-free' can be revived - metalink checksums match.
rpmfusion-free: using metadata from Sat 04 Nov 2023 12:49:08 PM EDT.
RPM Fusion for Fedora 39 - Free tainted                                                                                                                                                    11 kB/s | 3.3 kB     00:00    
reviving: 'rpmfusion-free-tainted' can be revived - metalink checksums match.
rpmfusion-free-tainted: using metadata from Tue 26 Sep 2023 06:32:09 AM EDT.
RPM Fusion for Fedora 39 - Free - Updates                                                                                                                                                  11 kB/s | 3.6 kB     00:00    
reviving: 'rpmfusion-free-updates' can be revived - metalink checksums match.
rpmfusion-free-updates: using metadata from Thu 30 Nov 2023 02:08:39 PM EST.
RPM Fusion for Fedora 39 - Nonfree                                                                                                                                                         21 kB/s | 6.8 kB     00:00    
reviving: 'rpmfusion-nonfree' can be revived - metalink checksums match.
rpmfusion-nonfree: using metadata from Sat 04 Nov 2023 01:26:32 PM EDT.
RPM Fusion for Fedora 39 - Nonfree - NVIDIA Driver                                                                                                                                         69 kB/s | 6.7 kB     00:00    
reviving: 'rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver' can be revived - metalink checksums match.
rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver: using metadata from Thu 30 Nov 2023 12:20:04 PM EST.
RPM Fusion for Fedora 39 - Nonfree - Steam                                                                                                                                                 19 kB/s | 6.2 kB     00:00    
reviving: 'rpmfusion-nonfree-steam' can be revived - metalink checksums match.
rpmfusion-nonfree-steam: using metadata from Thu 10 Aug 2023 12:27:35 PM EDT.
RPM Fusion for Fedora 39 - Nonfree tainted                                                                                                                                                 19 kB/s | 6.3 kB     00:00    
reviving: 'rpmfusion-nonfree-tainted' can be revived - metalink checksums match.
rpmfusion-nonfree-tainted: using metadata from Tue 26 Sep 2023 06:33:09 AM EDT.
RPM Fusion for Fedora 39 - Nonfree - Updates                                                                                                                                               20 kB/s | 6.6 kB     00:00    
reviving: 'rpmfusion-nonfree-updates' can be revived - metalink checksums match.
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: using metadata from Thu 30 Nov 2023 02:28:33 PM EST.
--> Starting dependency resolution
---> Package filesystem.x86_64 3.18-2.fc37 will be upgraded
---> Package filesystem.x86_64 3.18-6.fc39 will be an upgrade
--> Finished dependency resolution
Dependencies resolved.
==========================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                               Architecture                                      Version                                                  Repository                                         Size
==========================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Upgrading:
 filesystem                                            x86_64                                            3.18-6.fc39                                              fedora                                            1.1 M

Transaction Summary
==========================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Upgrade  1 Package

Total download size: 1.1 M
Downloading Packages:
filesystem-3.18-6.fc39.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                          12 MB/s | 1.1 MB     00:00    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                                                                     4.7 MB/s | 1.1 MB     00:00     
Using rpmkeys executable at /usr/bin/rpmkeys to verify signatures
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Running scriptlet: filesystem-3.18-6.fc39.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                    1/1 
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                                                                                                  1/1 
  Upgrading        : filesystem-3.18-6.fc39.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                    1/2 
Error unpacking rpm package filesystem-3.18-6.fc39.x86_64
Errors occurred during transaction.
  Verifying        : filesystem-3.18-6.fc39.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                    1/2 
  Verifying        : filesystem-3.18-2.fc37.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                    2/2 
Completion plugin: Generating completion cache...
Failed: filesystem-3.18-2.fc37.x86_64
Failed: filesystem-3.18-6.fc39.x86_64

Failed:
  filesystem-3.18-2.fc37.x86_64                                                                               filesystem-3.18-6.fc39.x86_64                                                                              

Error: Transaction failed
```

I have applied all post-upgrade suggestions from Fedora Docs and tried a few generic solutions for similar package issues. All to no avail. I also tried to remove/update filesystem package with yum (in addition to dnf) as a root but that gives me the same transaction error.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the verbose `dnf` logs for that transaction so everyone can better see what may be failing within the transaction?  `sudo dnf update --allowerasing -y --refresh --verbose`

Comment: @GracefulRestart, Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my question, adding the output of sudo dnf update --allowerasing -y --refresh --verbose

Comment: I also tried the following: downloaded the filesystem-3.18-6.fc39.x86_64.rpm package and used "rpm -Uivh /path-to-package/filesystem-3.18-6.fc39.x86_64 --force --replacepkgs" but got the error stating that the package files already reside in a directory of the system.

Answer (score 0):

The error that stands out is:

```
Error unpacking rpm package filesystem-3.18-6.fc39.x86_64
```

Which is strange. As if download was bad or your computer memory tends to get corrupted. I doubt file itself from repo was broken.

Either way, good to try `dnf clean all` and try to install it again. To be sur to download it again.